# Check if email exist or not with php, verified domain, mx, email pattern still not getting valid result

Tags: javascript, php, email, dns, email-validation

Tring to write php code to identify whether email id exists or not to prevent mail bounces. However below written code sometimes yields wrong results. 
For example, I got mail bounce for **michael@act-tec.com** and **alfiras@emirates.net.ae** email ids. But when checked with below code, i get valid result for later one which is wrong and invalid result for first email id which is correct. I dont know what else check I am missing in this code. Tried many things from past 1 week but badly stuck. Please help

```
       $isValid = 1;
       $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
       if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
       {
          $isValid = 0;
       }
       else
       {
          $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
          $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
          $localLen = strlen($local);
          $domainLen = strlen($domain);
          if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
          {
             // local part length exceeded
             $isValid = 0;
          }
          else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
          {
             // domain part length exceeded
             $isValid = 0;
          }
          else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
          {
             // local part starts or ends with '.'
             $isValid = 0;
          }
          else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
          {
             // local part has two consecutive dots
             $isValid = 0;
          }
          else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
          {
             // character not valid in domain part
             $isValid = 0;
          }
          else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
          {
             // domain part has two consecutive dots
             $isValid = 0;
          }
          else if(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/', str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
          {
             // character not valid in local part unless 
             // local part is quoted
             if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/', str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
             {
                $isValid = 0;
             }
          }
          if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))  {
             // domain not found in DNS
             $isValid = 0;
            }
            return $isValid;
        }
```

Comment: You are more or less only checking if the syntax is correct, and if an MX or A record for the domain exists. Of course that says nothing whatsoever about whether that e-mail address actually exists. This is basically the same as if you took the sentence “Foo Bar lives in London”, and you only check two things, whether the “syntax” of that sentence is correct, and that a city named London exists on the map. Drawing the conclusion that there was actually someone named Foo Bar living in London based on that is of course just wrong.

Comment: ok got it. So how can we validate username, I am not an expert in php and this is my 1st assignment. Any help will be appreciated. Thankyou for pointing out the problem.

Comment: Can someone help me out with this. How can we validate username for valid domain

Comment: The tool you mentioned in response to the existing answer already explains what it does to check, right there on the site.

Comment: Yes. But I want php code for that. The site is just an example for the expected output, but my code is still incomplete. Please help me out with that.

Comment: Any help ? Can anyone help me out with the missing piece of code. I know whats the problem but not able to code it.

Comment: If this is your first assignment, it's an impossible task as it cannot be completed. What you are asking to be done, cannot exactly be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the email syntax and check if MX (Mail exchange) servers exists, but that is pretty much it.

You cannot be 100% sure that certain email account exists in the email provider.

Even dough when sending email to some account in the major email providers, they respond that certain email account exists and allow email to be sent. Later you may receive **not delivered message**

Comment: yes. But if we use online tools like https://email-checker.net/check and check for alfiras@emirates.net.ae, they give correct result as does not exist. Which means there is some problem in my code

Comment: The only way to check if email account exists is to start sending the message and wait for response from the provider. The biggest providers always report that the account exists.